# How to access pages without adding .HTML extention to the urls in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm working in an AEM project and part of development we are accessing the content using `http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/xyz/en/app.html`.

While navigating to another page it is redirecting me to `http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/xyz/en/inko-app` (observe carefully the link is without `.html` extension) and in order to see the new webpage I had to add `.html` extension manually.

Is there anyway I can automate this only for development environment?

Versions used:
AEM: 6.3
build version :20170420

I have gone through [Adding .html extension to page selected](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2324782) but it is not quite useful

Comment: The AEM default behaviour is to access pages with .html always. So your project seems to have configs or code that prevents this. I guess you are in preview mode?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am in Author mode and want to navigate in between pages without publisher instance

Comment: Sure, but - just to get things right on my end - are you in edit mode or iin preview mode on your author instance? I am asking because links should not be clickable if you open a page in edit mode. Can you check if there really is a redirect or if the link is pointing directly to the target url (without suffix)?

Comment: Yes, I'm in a preview mode. Link is pointing directly to the target url without suffix

Comment: @GangadharJannu, of course you can do, have you thought of writing Sling rewriter which will be applicable to development server?

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if in your sightly or java where you are declaring the page path, have you added .html as extension or not?.

For exmaple :

In your sightly if you are getting page path as `"${currentPage.path}"`, the value will be without html, you need to explicitly add .html to
`"${currentPage.path}.html"` like this.

Comment: this is not good way to add extension, you should do : ${currentPage.path @ extension = 'html'}

Comment: @Pakira You should write this as an answer, so people can see